# Ecto syntax for seeding JSON data

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am new to Elixir and Phoenix, and I can't figure out the proper syntax to use in my seeds.exs file to insert JSON into a Postgres JSON column. Here is an example of what I am trying to insert.

```
Repo.insert! %Language{
    page: "accounts",
    code: "en-us",
    mode: "all",
    language: { "username_email" : "Username or email address", 
                 "password" : "Password", 
                 "invalid_username_password" : "Invalid username or password"
              }
}, prefix: :lookups
```

but nothing I have tried works. I just need to insert literal JSON into the DB.

Comment: `language: {` is a syntax error. You want a map. not a tuple there: `language: %{`. With this single percent sign added everything should just work.

Comment: That makes it crash on the colon. When I replace the colon, I get  the following. 
** (CompileError) priv/repo/seeds.exs:42: Language.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Language
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:146: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/5
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:85: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:316: Mix.Task.run_task/

Comment: Ah, of course, remove quotes around keys, it should be `language: %{username_email: "Username or email address", password: "Password", invalid_username_password: "Invalid username or password"}`. No spaces between keys and colons as well. It’s Elixir not Javascript.

Comment: Also, you must define `Language` struct before using it. Have you forgotten the FQ-name?

Comment: That did it! Thanks! If you will make this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this code.

Elixir maps have a following syntax:

```
map = %{foo: 42, bar: :baz}
```

Note the percent sign in from of it, the lack of space between the key and the colon and that keys are indeed written without quotes. When one needs to use strings as keys, it’s still possible with a hashrocket syntax:

```
map = %{"foo" => 42}
```

but that is not what you need here.

Also, according to the error message posted, you likely forgot to alias your `Language` struct and/or use a fully-qualified name for it. The summing up, the correct code would be:

```
Repo.insert! %MyData.Language{
  page: "accounts",
  code: "en-us",
  mode: "all",
  language: %{
    username_email: "Username or email address",
    password: "Password",
    invalid_username_password: "Invalid"
  }
}, prefix: :lookups
```